# How do you intercept xhr POST parameters / POST body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I know how to intercept AJAX calls with XMLHttpRequest.

I looked at the docs and there is no mentioning of the parameters (POST body) .

How do I intercept those using XMLHttpRequest.

I'm trying to keep track of all the AJAX requests run on a web page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This is how you do it:

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.realSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send; 
var newSend = function(vData) { console.log("data: " + vData); this.realSend(vData); };
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = newSend;
```